# How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky-footer

I have a simple 2-column layout with a footer that clears both the right and left div in my markup.  My problem is that I can't get the footer to stay at the bottom of the page in all browsers.  It works if the content pushes the footer down, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

To get a sticky footer:

1. Have a `<div>` with `class="wrapper"` for your content.
2. Right **before** the closing `</div>` of the `wrapper` place the
   `<div class="push"></div>`.
3. Right **after** the closing `</div>` of the `wrapper` place the
   `<div class="footer"></div>`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">wrapper
    <div class="push">push</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: @jlp: You need to add the form tag to the height:100% statement, else it will break the sticky footer. Like this:
html, body, form {height: 100%;}

Comment: I noticed that adding padding to the footer screws it, but figured out that that can be fixed by subtracting the extra padding on the footer from the {footer, push} height.

Comment: The detailed explanation with the demo is provided in this site: [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer)

Comment: Hey I followed your steps and it works pretty well for big pages. But on small pages where the user is not able to scroll down the footer is a little to far at the bottom. So it makes a nearly empty page scrollable. Anyone knows how to fix this? You can see my test page here https://sheltered-escarpment-6887.herokuapp.com/

Comment: BTW, instead of adding a .push div, you can also use .wrapper::after to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Syk I've found that reducing the min-height helps.  94% is an ok value, but you still see the issue on mobile :(  Not sure there's a real solution here.

Comment: If your footer is just text, it might be better to set the height in em's, eg for one line of text `height: 1.5em` Then users that set magnification will still be able to see the text.

Answer (score 110):

### Use CSS vh units!

Probably the most obvious and non-hacky way to go about a sticky footer would be to make use of the new [css viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Take for example the following simple markup:

```
<header>header goes here</header>
<div class="content">This page has little content</div>
<footer>This is my footer</footer>
```

If the header is say 80px high and the footer is 40px high, then we can make our sticky footer *with one single rule* on the content div:

```
.content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    /* 80px header + 40px footer = 120px  */
}
```

Which means: let the height of the content div be **at least** 100% of the viewport height minus the combined heights of the header and footer.

That's it.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header {
    background: yellow;
    height: 80px;
}
.content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    /* 80px header + 40px footer = 120px  */
    background: pink;
}
footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<header>header goes here</header>
<div class="content">This page has little content</div>
<footer>This is my footer</footer>
```

... and here's how the same code works with lots of content in the content div:

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header {
    background: yellow;
    height: 80px;
}
.content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    /* 80px header + 40px footer = 120px  */
    background: pink;
}
footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<header>header goes here</header>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
</div>
<footer>
    This is my footer
</footer>
```

**NB:**

1) The height of the header and footer must be known

2) Old versions of IE (IE8-) and Android (4.4-) don't support viewport units. ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units/embed/))

3) Once upon a time webkit had a problem with viewport units within a calc rule. This has indeed been fixed ([see here](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/06/12/improving-viewport-unit-support-in-webkit/)) so there's no problem there. However if you're looking to avoid using calc for some reason you can get around that using negative margins and padding with box-sizing -

Like so:

```css
* {
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
header {
    background: yellow;
    height: 80px;
    position:relative;
}
.content {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: pink;
    margin: -80px 0 -40px;
    padding: 80px 0 40px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<header>header goes here</header>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum 
</div>
<footer>
    This is my footer
</footer>
```

Comment: How is messing with absolute measurements not still hacky? At best it's perhaps *less* hacky

Comment: But and if the height of footer and header is mensured in percent and not px? Like 15% of the page's height?

Comment: Viewport units don't always work as expected on mobile browsers that hide or show address bar depending on scroll position

Answer (score 88):

## Sticky footer with `display: flex`

Solution inspired by [Philip Walton's sticky footer](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/).

### Explanation

This solution is [valid only for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Browser_compatibility):

- Chrome ≥ 21.0
- Firefox ≥ 20.0
- Internet Explorer ≥ 10
- Safari ≥ 6.1

It is based on the [`flex` display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex), leveraging the `flex-grow` property, which allows an element to *grow* in either **height** or **width** (when the `flow-direction` is set to either `column` or `row` respectively), to occupy the extra space in the container.

We are going to leverage also the `vh` unit, where `1vh` is [defined as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths):

> 1/100th of the height of the viewport

Therefore a height of `100vh` it's a concise way to tell an element to span the full viewport's height.

This is how you would structure your web page:

```
----------- body -----------
----------------------------

---------- footer ----------
----------------------------
```

In order to have the footer stick to the bottom of the page, you want the space between the body and the footer to grow as much as it takes to push the footer at the bottom of the page.

Therefore our layout becomes:

```
----------- body -----------
----------------------------

---------- spacer ----------
                             <- This element must grow in height
----------------------------

---------- footer ----------
----------------------------
```

### Implementation

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.spacer {
    flex: 1;
}

/* make it visible for the purposes of demo */
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="content">Hello World!</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

You can play with it at [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzchhLjp/).

### Safari quirks

Be aware that Safari has a [flawed implementation of the `flex-shrink` property](http://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/#minimum-content-sizing-of-flex-items), which allows items to shrink more than the minimum height that would be required to display the content.
To fix this issue you will have to set the `flex-shrink` property explicitly to 0 to the `.content` and the `footer` in the above example:

```css
.content {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, change the `flex` style for the `spacer` element into:

```css
.spacer {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

This 3-value shorthand style is equivalent to the following full setup:

```css
.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

Elegantly works everywhere.

Comment: I feel this is the correct answer, since it's actually the only approach which works even when the height of the footer is not known.

Comment: This messes up the grid with Neat 2

Comment: But why not the  Philip Walton's solution itself, why an extra "spacer" element?

Comment: @YakovL In Walton's solution `.Site-content` element plays the same role as `spacer`. It's just called differently.

Comment: @Gherman well, `.Site-content` has an analog `.content` in this markup.. but nevermind, I asked for the case gcedo has some specific idea about it, no need to guess

Comment: @YakovL Indeed one tag seems redundant somewhat.

Comment: Very similar to the [solution by @ferit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071640/327301). However ferit gets along without the spacer, simply by using `margin-top: auto` on the footer.

Answer (score 29):

You could use `position: absolute` following to put the footer at the bottom of the page, but then make sure your 2 columns have the appropriate `margin-bottom` so that they never get occluded by the footer.

```css
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
#content, #sidebar { 
    margin-bottom: 5em; 
}
```

Comment: I've tried this with my similar setup (two columns + footer) and it does not work.

Comment: It overlap with content if content grow.

Comment: that's why content has the margin-bottom. you have to set it to whatever fixed height you make the footer.

Comment: For what it's worth, if something is a zero value it does not matter what measuring unit it is in, nothing is nothing, so all the `0px`s in all the stylesheets I've seen should be just `0`.

Comment: what if height of page is more than the display's height or content length of footer is dynamic? View my answer for solution of this problem.

Comment: l have tried this but not working footer breaks on right side.

Comment: it will overlaps the content if the body grows more than current vh

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution with jQuery that works like a charm. It checks if the height of the window is greater than the height of the body. If it is, then it changes the margin-top of the footer to compensate. Tested in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

```
$( function () {

    var height_diff = $( window ).height() - $( 'body' ).height();
    if ( height_diff > 0 ) {
        $( '#footer' ).css( 'margin-top', height_diff );
    }

});
```

If your footer already has a margin-top (of 50 pixels, for example) you will need to change the last part for:

```
css( 'margin-top', height_diff + 50 )
```

Comment: One alternative is to add a "pusher" div right before the footer.  Then set the height of the pusher div.  This avoids having to deal with existing margin-top

Answer (score 12):

Set the CSS for the `#footer` to:

```css
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

You will then need to add a `padding` or `margin` to the bottom of your `#sidebar` and `#content` to match the height of `#footer` or when they overlap, the `#footer` will cover them.

Also, if I remember correctly, IE6 has a problem with the `bottom: 0` CSS. You might have to use a JS solution for IE6 (if you care about IE6 that is).

Comment: when the window is too small, the footer shows up in front of the content with this css.

Answer (score 8):

A similar solution to [@gcedo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34146411/8620333) but without the need of adding an intermediate content in order to push the footer down. We can simply add `margin-top:auto` to the footer and it will be pushed to the bottom of the page regardless his height or the height of the content above.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
}

.content {
  padding: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding:10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  some content here
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  some content
</footer>
```

Comment: Another approach would be to give `.content` `flex: 1 0 auto;` to make it growable and non-shinkable, but `margin-top: auto;` is a nice trick that involves styling footer, not "non-related" `.content` which is nice. Actually, I wonder why flex is needed in this approach..

Comment: @YakovL yes the main idea here is the margin-top trick ;) I know that I can make the content like this but it will be almost the same as a previous answer where the idea is to push the footer by the content ... and here I wanted to avoid this and push the footer only with margin;)

Comment: @YakovL flex is needed for the margin:auto :) we cannot use it without it ... as margin:auto behave slightly different with flex item then block items. If you remove `display:flex` it won't work, you will have a normal block element flow

Comment: Yeah, I can see that it won't work without it, but I don't understand why (what's "slightly different")

Comment: @YakovL it's simple, using normal block element the flow is always a row direction so only margin right/left used with auto will work (like the famous `margin:0 auto` to center block element) BUT we don't have any column direction so there is no margin auto with top/bottom. Flexbox has both row/column direction ;). This is the slight difference, but margin is also used within flexbox to align element so even within a row direction you can use margin-top/bottom auto to align vertically .. You can read more here : https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins

Answer (score 4):

Just invented a very simple solution that worked great for me. You just wrap all page content except for the footer within in a div, and then set the min-height to 100% of the viewpoint minus the height of the footer. No need for absolute positioning on the footer or multiple wrapper divs.

```css
.page-body {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 400px);
} /*Replace 400px with your footer height*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I have myself struggled with this sometimes and I always found that the solution with all those div's within each other was a messy solution. 
I just messed around with it a bit, and I personally found out that this works and it certainly is one of the simplest ways:

```
html {
    position: relative;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

What I like about this is that no extra HTML needs to be applied. You can simply add this CSS and then write your HTML as whenever

Comment: This worked me, however i added width:100% to the footer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) solution hasn't been presented yet, here it is, with just two *declarations* for the *parent element*, if we take the `height: 100%` and `margin: 0` for granted:

```css
html, body {height: 100%}

body {
  display: grid; /* generates a block-level grid */
  align-content: space-between; /* places an even amount of space between each grid item, with no space at the far ends */
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  background: lightgreen;
  /* demo / for default snippet window */
  height: 1em;
  animation: height 2.5s linear alternate infinite;
}

footer {background: lightblue}

@keyframes height {to {height: 250px}}
```

```html
<div class="content">Content</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

- [`align-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)

> The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along
>   the cross axis. The spacing between each pair of adjacent items is the
>   same. The first item is flush with the main-start edge, and the last
>   item is flush with the main-end edge.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning and z-index to create a sticky footer div at any resolution using the following steps:

- Create a footer div with `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` and the desired height
- Set the padding of the footer to add whitespace between the content bottom and the window bottom
- Create a container `div` that wraps the body content with `position: relative; min-height: 100%;`
- Add bottom padding to the main content `div` that is equal to the height plus padding of the footer
- Set the `z-index` of the footer greater than the container `div` if the footer is clipped

Here is an example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sticky Footer</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      .wrapper { position: relative; min-height: 100%; }
      .footer { position: absolute; bottom:0; width: 100%; height: 200px; padding-top: 100px; background-color: gray; }
      .column { height: 2000px; padding-bottom: 300px; background-color: grxqeen; }
      /* Set the `html`, `body`, and container `div` to `height: 100%` for IE6 */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="column">
        <span>hello</span>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>This is a test. This is only a test...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS :

```
  #container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            }
 #container.footer{
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            height:20vh;
            margin-top:80vh;
            background-color:red;
            }
```

HTML:

```
           <div id="container">
               <div class="footer">
               </div>
           </div>
```

This should do the trick if you are looking for a responsive footer aligned at the bottom of the page,which always keeps a top-margin of 80% of the viewport height.

Answer (score 1):

For this question many of the answers I have seen are clunky, hard to implement and inefficient so I thought I'd take a shot at it and come up with my own solution which is just a tiny bit of css and html

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.body {
  min-height: calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.footer {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="body">test as body</div>
  <div class="footer">test as footer</div>
</body>
```

this works by setting the height of the footer and then using css calc to work out the minimum height the page can be with the footer still at the bottom, hope this helps some people :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it using position fixed, and following you annoyingly on mobile, this seems to be working for me so far.

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#site-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 2px;
    background: #32383e;
}
```

Just set the html to `min-height: 100%;` and `position: relative;`, then `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;` on the footer. I then made sure the footer was the last element in the body.

Let me know if this doesn't work for anyone else, and why. I know these tedious style hacks can behave strangely among various circumstances I'd not thought of.

Comment: +1 This is how I do it too... the only problem with this is that it can overlap the content, but you can easily fix that by adding the footer twice in a row to the page, and setting the style of the first one to `visibility: hidden; position: static;`. This will make it so that the body (including default margins and padding) perfectly aligns with the visible footer, because since the hidden footer is now part of the body's content, the visible footer will now only overlap the hidden footer, causing perfect alignment with the body. Makes it easy to add a footer to already existing content. :)

Answer (score 1):

On my sites I always use:

```
position: fixed;
```

...in my CSS for a footer. That anchors it to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Doing this will make the footer overlap the content

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set the min-height for the boxes. Unfortunately it seems that [it's not well supported by IE](http://www.wellstyled.com/css-minheight-hack.html) (surprise).

Answer (score 0):

None of these pure css solutions work properly with dynamically resizing content (at least on firefox and Safari) e.g., if you have a background set on the container div, the page and then resize (adding a few rows) table inside the div, the table can stick out of the bottom of the styled area, i.e., you can have half the table in white on black theme and half the table complete white because both the font-color and background color is white. It's basically unfixable with themeroller pages.

Nested div multi-column layout is an ugly hack and the 100% min-height body/container div for sticking footer is an uglier hack.

The only none-script solution that works on all the browsers I've tried: a much simpler/shorter table with thead (for header)/tfoot (for footer)/tbody (td's for any number of columns) and 100% height. But this have perceived semantic and SEO disadvantages (tfoot must appear before tbody. ARIA roles may help decent search engines though).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple people have put the answer to this simple problem up here, but I have one thing to add, considering how frustrated I was until I figured out what I was doing wrong.

As mentioned the most straightforward way to do this is like so..

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: static;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.site-footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

However the property not mentioned in posts, presumably because it is usually default, is the **position: static** on the body tag. Position relative will not work!

My wordpress theme had overridden the default body display and it confused me for an obnoxiously long time.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery CROSS BROWSER CUSTOM PLUGIN - $.footerBottom()**

Or use jQuery like I do, and set your footer height to `auto` or to `fix`, whatever you like, it will work anyway. this plugin uses jQuery selectors so to make it work, you will have to include the jQuery library to your file.

Here is how you run the plugin. Import jQuery, copy the code of this custom jQuery plugin and import it after importing jQuery! It is very simple and basic, but important.

When you do it, all you have to do is run this code:

```
$.footerBottom({target:"footer"}); //as html5 tag <footer>.
// You can change it to your preferred "div" with for example class "footer" 
// by setting target to {target:"div.footer"}
```

there is no need to place it inside the document ready event. It will run well as it is. It will recalculate the position of your footer when the page is loaded and when the window get resized.

Here is the code of the plugin which you do not have to understand. Just know how to implement it. It does the job for you. However, if you like to know how it works, just look through the code. I left comments for you.

```
//import jQuery library before this script
```

```js
// Import jQuery library before this script

// Our custom jQuery Plugin
(function($) {
  $.footerBottom = function(options) { // Or use "$.fn.footerBottom" or "$.footerBottom" to call it globally directly from $.footerBottom();
    var defaults = {
      target: "footer",
      container: "html",
      innercontainer: "body",
      css: {
        footer: {
          position: "absolute",
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
        },

        html: {
          position: "relative",
          minHeight: "100%"
        }
      }
    };

    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    // JUST SET SOME CSS DEFINED IN THE DEFAULTS SETTINGS ABOVE
    $(options.target).css({
      "position": options.css.footer.position,
      "left": options.css.footer.left,
      "bottom": options.css.footer.bottom,
    });

    $(options.container).css({
      "position": options.css.html.position,
      "min-height": options.css.html.minHeight,
    });

    function logic() {
      var footerOuterHeight = $(options.target).outerHeight(); // Get outer footer height
      $(options.innercontainer).css('padding-bottom', footerOuterHeight + "px"); // Set padding equal to footer height on body element
      $(options.target).css('height', footerOuterHeight + "!important"); // Set outerHeight of footer element to ... footer
      console.log("jQ custom plugin footerBottom runs"); // Display text in console so ou can check that it works in your browser. Delete it if you like.
    };

    // DEFINE WHEN TO RUN FUNCTION
    $(window).on('load resize', function() { // Run on page loaded and on window resized
      logic();
    });

    // RETURN OBJECT FOR CHAINING IF NEEDED - IF NOT DELETE
    // return this.each(function() {
    //   this.checked = true;
    // });
    // return this;
  };
})(jQuery); // End of plugin


// USE EXAMPLE
$.footerBottom(); // Run our plugin with all default settings for HTML5
```

```css
/* Set your footer CSS to what ever you like it will work anyway */
footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The structure doesn't matter much, you will always have html and body tag, so just make sure to point to your footer as needed if you use html5, as it should just do nothing run plugin with no settings it will work by default with the <footer> html5 tag -->
<body>
  <div class="content">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>link</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
      <p></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
    <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
    <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Vanilla java-script is less lengthy than plugin.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread I know, but if you are looking for a responsive solution, this jQuery addition will help:

```
$(window).on('resize',sticky);
$(document).bind("ready", function() {
   sticky();
});

function sticky() {
   var fh = $("footer").outerHeight();
   $("#push").css({'height': fh});
   $("#wrapper").css({'margin-bottom': -fh});
}
```

Full guide can be found here: https://pixeldesigns.co.uk/blog/responsive-jquery-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a very simple library https://github.com/ravinderpayal/FooterJS

It is very simple in use. After including library, just call this line of code.

```
footer.init(document.getElementById("ID_OF_ELEMENT_CONTAINING_FOOTER"));
```

Footers can be dynamically changed by recalling above function with different parameter/id.

```
footer.init(document.getElementById("ID_OF_ANOTHER_ELEMENT_CONTAINING_FOOTER"));
```

Note:- You haven't to alter or add any CSS. Library is dynamic which implies that even if screen is resized after loading page it will reset the position of footer. I have created this library, because CSS solves the problem for a while but when size of display changes significantly,from desktop to tablet or vice versa, they either overlap the content or they no longer remains sticky.

Another solution is CSS Media Queries, but you have to manually write different CSS styles for different size of screens while this library does its work automatically and is supported by all basic JavaScript supporting browser.

**Edit**
CSS solution:

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 768px) {/* or height/length of body content including footer*/
    /* For mobile phones: */
    #footer {
        width: 100%;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
    }
}
```

Now, if the height of display is more than your content length, we will make footer fixed to bottom and if not, it will automatically appear in very end of display as you need to scroll to view this.

And, it seems a better solution than JavaScript/library one.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't having any luck with the solutions suggested on this page before but then finally, this little trick worked. I'll include it as another possible solution.

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For natural header and footer heights use CSS Flexbox.

[See JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsb6dk14/).

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <header>
    ...
  </header>
  <main>
    ...
  </main>
  <footer>
    ...
  </footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

header,
footer {
  flex: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the nicest way of displaying it (the footer) is sticking to the bottom but not covering content all the time:

```
#my_footer {
    position: static
    fixed; bottom: 0
}
```

Comment: Is this syntax correct? Is position supposed to be static or fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The flex solutions worked for me as far as making the footer sticky, but unfortunately changing the body to use flex layout made some of our page layouts change, and not for the better. What finally worked for me was:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var fht = jQuery('footer').outerHeight(true);
    jQuery('main').css('min-height', "calc(92vh - " + fht + "px)");

});
```

I got this from ctf0's response at https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<body style="height:1500px">

   <h2>position: fixed;</h2>

   <p>An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled:</p>

   <div class="fixed">
      This div element has position: fixed;
   </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

## REACT-friendly solution - (no spacer div required)

Chris Coyier (the venerable CSS-Tricks website) has kept his [page on the Sticky-Footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) up-to-date, with at least FIVE methods now for creating a sticky footer, including using FlexBox and CSS-Grid.

Why is this important? Because, for me, the earlier/older methods I used for years did not work with React - I had to use Chris' flexbox solution - which was ***easy*** and ***worked***.

Below is his [CSS-Tricks flexbox Sticky Footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#there-is-flexbox) - just look at the code below, it cannot possibly be simpler.

*(The (below) StackSnippet example does not perfectly render the bottom of the example. The footer is shown extending past the bottom of the screen, which does not happen in real life.)*

```css
html,body{height: 100%;}
body     {display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
.content {flex: 1 0 auto;} /* flex: grow / shrink / flex-basis; */
.footer  {flex-shrink: 0;}

/* ---- BELOW IS ONLY for demo ---- */
.footer{background: palegreen;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">Page Content - height expands to fill space</div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer Content</footer>
</body>
```

Chris also demonstrates this [CSS-Grid solution](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#there-is-grid) for those who prefer grid.

---

#### References:

[CSS-Tricks - A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://1linelayouts.glitch.me/, example 4. Una Kravets nails this problem.

This creates a 3 layer page with header, main and footer.

-Your footer will always stay at the bottom, and use space to fit the content;

-Your header will always stay at the top, and use space to fit the content;

-Your main will always use all the available remaining space (remaining fraction of space), enough to fill the screen, if need.

### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <header class="blue section" contenteditable>Header</header>
  <main class="coral section" contenteditable>Main</main>
  <footer class="purple section" contenteditable>Footer Content</footer>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  height: 95vh; /* no scroll bars if few content */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick easy solution by using flex

- Give the `html` and `body` a height of `100%`

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

- Display the body as `flex` with `column` direction:

```css
body { 
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

- Add `flex-grow: 1` for the main

```css
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

> `flex-grow` specifies how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to the item (the flex grow factor).

```css
*, 
*::after,
*::before{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

footer{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <main>
        <section >
            Hero
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer >
        <div>
            <p > &copy; Copyright 2021</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your `<main>` as min-height 90vh will solve your problem forever.
Here is the base structure that will help you follow semantics and cover entire page.

**Step 1:** Keep everything inside the main tag except the header and footer.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <!╌ nav, logo ╌> 
    </header>
    <main>
        <!╌ section and div ╌> 
    </main>
    <footer>
        <!╌ nav, logo ╌>
    </footer>
</body>
```

**Step 2:** Add min-height: 90vh for main

```
main{
    min-height: 90vh;
}
```

Usually, header and footer are 70px minimum in height so this case works well, tried and tested!

Answer (score 0):

Most answers use css with fixed values. While it might work, the fixed values for the footer size need to be adjusted when the footer changes. Also, I'm using WordPress and don't want to mess with the footer sizes the WordPress theme defines for you.

I solved it with a little bit of javascript that only triggers when required.

```
    var fixedFooter = false;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {fixFooterToBottom();}, false);
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {fixFooterToBottom();}, false);
    function fixFooterToBottom()
    {
        var docClientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var body = document.querySelector("body");
        var footer = document.querySelector("footer");

        fixedFooter = fixedFooter ? (body.clientHeight  + footer.clientHeight ) < docClientHeight :  body.clientHeight < docClientHeight;
        footer.style.position = fixedFooter ? "fixed" : "unset";
        footer.style.left = fixedFooter ? 0 : "unset";
        footer.style.right = fixedFooter ? 0 : "unset";
        footer.style.bottom = fixedFooter ? 0 : "unset";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't see this answer here:

I wanted to artificially enlarge the website to see if it would stick to the bottom. Then it becomes a bit more tricky. I tried doing it through setting the body to a very big height.

But yeah I found a very simple answer if you really want to stretch the page to see if it works:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1380px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

And then margin-top "sets" the size of the website, which is a bit weird. But it's simple, and it works.

It doesn't work with setting body height a certain (big) value and then setting footer from the bottom of that again. I tried putting the footer inside the body tag and behind the body tag also. Neither worked.

So this was my only possible answer. Posting it here for others.

Answer (score -2):

Try putting a container div (with overflow:auto) around the content and sidebar.

If that doesn't work, do you have any screenshots or example links where the footer isn't displayed properly?